# Jquery .change() only updates results one time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 input fields. #first, #second, and #third, as well as a fourth field #theResult.

```
<div id="addFields">
<span id="addFieldsHeader">Add The Fields</span>
<table style="margin:0 auto;">
    <tr>
    <td style="width:80px;">First
        <input id="first" size="5" value="3" name="first" style="width:75px" />
    </td>
    <td style="width:80px;">Second
        <input id="second" size="5" value="5" name="second" style="width:75px" />
    </td>
    <td style="width:80px;">Third
        <input id="third" size="6" maxlength="7" name="third" style="width:75px" value="0" />
    </td>
    <td style="width:80px;">Result
        <input id="theResult" size="7" maxlength="7" name="result" style="width:75px" value="0" />
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

I have tried to write a jQuery script that will add the values of #first, #second, and #third together and display the results in #theResult.

I did find docs for the .change() function [here](http://api.jquery.com/change/) which looked like it would suit my needs better than .blur() or .keyup(), as I want the value of #theResult to update each time the value of #first, #second, or #third is changed by the user.

I have the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var first = parseInt($("#first").val(), 10);
    var second = parseInt($("#second").val(), 10);
    var third = parseInt($("#third").val(), 10);
    var theResult = first + second + third;

    $("#addFields input").change(function () {
        $("#theResult").val(theResult);
    });
});
```

When I change a value in any of the inputs #theResult does update, but it only works once and after that I have to reload the page again to get it to work. Also, only the initial values are added, not the updated values. Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RqzPk/24/)

Anyone with experience I greatly appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addFields input").change(function() {
        var first = parseInt($("#first").val(),10);
        var second = parseInt($("#second").val(),10);
        var third = parseInt($("#third").val(),10);
        var theResult = first + second + third;
        $("#theResult").val(theResult);
    });
});
```

You just have to move the variables inside the `change()` function, so it updates each time.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RqzPk/25/)

Comment: Works great! Thanks for help. I learned that I must place variables inside of function if I want the function to effect them each time it is called!

Comment: No problem! Great to see more people learning on this website, who ask quality questions.

Answer (score 0):

You Only need to bring you variables in the change function

```
$("#addFields input" ).change(function() {

    var first = parseInt($("#first").val(),10);
    var second = parseInt($("#second").val(),10);
    var third = parseInt($("#third").val(),10);
    var theResult = first + second + third;
    $("#theResult").val(theResult);
});
```

it because the new value is not assigned to those variables

Comment: Why did you change `change()` to `keyup()`? OP stated `change()` was what he wanted to use.

Comment: Actually, now that I have tested "keyup" IS what I wanted. Just hadn't seen it in action before. This way #theResult updates as soon as user changes one of the fields instead of when clicking elsewhere http://jsfiddle.net/RqzPk/27/. It seems like .change() behaves a lot like .onBlur

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this:**

```
$(function() {

     $("#addFields input" ).change(function() {
     var first = parseInt($("#first").val(),10);
     var second = parseInt($("#second").val(),10);
     var third = parseInt($("#third").val(),10);
     var theResult = first + second + third;
     $("#theResult").val(theResult);
});
});
```